# Oracle SQL Transposing Only One column values as separate columns in the output

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My SQL;

```
    SELECT
        created_date,
        response_status,
        count
    FROM
        t_bvs_txn_response_summary
    WHERE
        created_date > SYSDATE - 1 / 24
        AND   response_status IN (
            'successful',
            'Disconnection'
        )
    ORDER BY
        1;
```

has following output;

[image: Current Output]

I want to take the values in column response_status in separate columns and show the counts against each of them for a particular instance.

The desired output will be some thing like this;

[image: Desired Output]

I am new to SQL so need some help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try PIVOT

```
SELECT * FROM (
     SELECT
            created_date, 
            response_status,
            nvl(count,0) as count
        FROM
            t_bvs_txn_response_summary
        WHERE
            created_date > SYSDATE - 1 / 24
            AND   response_status IN (
                'successful',
                'Disconnection'
            )
)
PIVOT
(
  SUM(count)
  FOR response_status IN ('successful', 'Disconnection')
)
        ORDER BY
            1;
```

Comment: No. This is just grouping by response_status column which is not the desired output. I have updated the question and shown desired output.

Comment: with little changes to your code it worked but need to show zero instead of NULL in case there is nothing found for that particular instance.

I had to add       count    in the inner select and then sum function after pivot.

Comment: if you edit your code, this can be marked as Correct answer.

Comment: @khalidmehmoodawan I edited now my code as per your comment

Comment: May if you work on showing 0 instead of nulls in case where no count/sum is found, this will further improve the answer.

Thanks .

Comment: @khalidmehmoodawan I added NVL(count,0), it should do the trick

Answer (score 4):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
    SELECT 
      created_date,
      sum(case when response_status='successful' then count end ) as 'successful',
      sum(case when response_status='Disconnection' then count end) as 'Disconnection'
      FROM t_bvs_txn_response_summary
      WHERE created_date > SYSDATE - 1 / 24 AND response_status IN ('successful', 'Disconnection')
      group by created_date
```

Comment: Yes this one also worked but can we use pivot and avoid IF and case ?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is only used if you want to retrieve all remaining columns and counts also. counts will be repeated.

```
   SELECT
        created_date,
        response_status,
        count,count(*) over(partition by response_status)
    FROM
        t_bvs_txn_response_summary
    WHERE
        created_date > SYSDATE - 1 / 24
        AND   response_status IN (
            'successful',
            'Disconnection'
        )
    ORDER BY
        1;
```